# JMock Expectations, iterating through List

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, tdd, jmock

I have a list with Strings:

```
final List<String> serialNumbers=new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i=0;i<numberOfPieces;i++){
     serialNumbers.add(Integer.toString(i));
}
```

Now I want my MockObject to return the next element in the List as a String everytime the mock method is called, how do I do this?

```
context.checking(new Expectations(){{
     exactly(numberOfPieces).of (myMock).getSerialNumber();
     // will return serialNumbers i-th element
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: use `onConsecutiveCalls` as it can take an Array of Actions.

```
final ReturnValueAction[] serialNumbers=new ReturnValueAction[numberOfPieces];

for(int i=0;i<numberOfPieces;i++){
     serialNumbers[i]=new ReturnValueAction(Integer.toString(i)); 
}

context.checking(new Expectations(){{
     exactly(numberOfPieces).of (myMock).getSerialNumber();
     will(onConsecutiveCalls(serialNumbers)); 
}});
```